# Using boto3 to retrieve groups of ec2 instance objects from ec2 resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

PROBLEM DESCIPTION:

From a specific aws region, I need the list of running instance objects in groups (say groups of 10). I am using the service resource filter as below.

ec2_service_resource = boto3.resource('ec2', region)

results = ec2_service_resource.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}], MaxResults=10)

As per boto3 docs, I should be able to retrieve the next group of results using the NextToken from the response of the first call. 
(https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.instances)

QUESTION:

I am not able to find the NextToken string in response object. Am I missing something? Is there a way I can achieve this using ec2 resource object?

Comment: Do you have more than 10 instances?

Comment: Yes. Its a production account, so the number of instances is expected to be be higher and only increasing with time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I observed the call (ec2_service_resource.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}], MaxResults=10)) returns an iterable of ec2 instances, which count to only 10 instance objects as specified in the MaxResults parameter.

However, while we keep iterating through this iterable, boto3 silently makes additional API call to AWS and fetches the next batch of (10) instances. 
I could confirm there is no need for NextToken here, as iterating through the iterable automatically makes the next data available in the response.

The NextToken string seems to be useless in this case. Not sure why boto3 have this misleading info in the documentation.